# Database table creation outside of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project that was built in Rails.  We're migrating away from Rails but we need it running until the migration is complete.

However, we do need to add one more table and don't want to do it through Rails.  Would it break the Rails application if I added the table manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strongly recommended to include in database migrations but adding one more table would not break the current flow as long as this new table does not conflict with existing tables and there is no more update about rails project. I got to think of the case when `User` model defined a custom table name `my_users` and you added a new table `users`. Custom defined table names have higher priority than originally matching table names so you would not worry.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it will continue to work normally.

The only problem I can think of is, if you are going to have constraints in your database between the existing tables and the new table that might prevent modifying data in the existing tables. In that case you will need to add some code in rails.